# How to get the content of all files in a given directory?

Tags: octokit.net

Octokit allows me to easily retrieve the list of files in a given folder like so:

```
var directoryContent = await _githubClient.Repository.Content.GetAllContents("MyUsername", "MyProject", "TheFolderName").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Unfortunately, the `Content` property for each file is `null` which means that I have to loop through the list of files and retrieve each one separately like so:

```
foreach (var file in directoryContent)
{
    var fileWithContent = await _githubClient.Repository.Content.GetAllContents("MyUsername", "MyProject", file.Path).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ... do something with the content ...
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to get the content of all files in a given folder?

Answer (score -1):

Just for reference: This is on purpose. If you read a whole directory and load all the content in one step it's huge load. So, the first call skips the content (`Content` property is `null`). The second step requests just this file and then the content is present.

Only thing I'm still missing is a method that can return just one result instead of a list if I pull a single file.